# How to config apache (installed in server) to run a web app (django) in docker?

Tags: docker, apache, deployment

I have an Apache server installed and running for 3 website in PHP. I also developed a mobile api in Django running on 4 docker containers
(Django, Redis, Elasticsearch, RabbitMQ using `fig.sh`).

Because Apache is running and I want to keep it and configure it to run the web app on the docker containers. If it is Django app I will config `mod_wsgi` for that but it is not so I don't know.

Note: I am using Docker 1.5 and Apache 2.2 on Centos 6.6.

Edit: Apache contains 3 `<VirtualHost *:80 >` for 3 domain of 3 website.

1  website1.com

2 website2.com

3 website3.com

and api I want to deploy is running on domain api.website1.com is subdomain of website1.com

fig.yml

```
db:
  image: mysql
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  volumes_from:
    - mysql_data
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
  # command:


redis:
 image: redis:3

elasticsearch:
 image: elasticsearch
 ports:
   - "9200:9200"
   - "9300:9300"

rabbitmq:
 image: tutum/rabbitmq
 environment:
   - RABBITMQ_PASS=123456
 ports:
   - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for debugging
   - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin

web:
  build: .
  command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"

  links:
   - db:db
   - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
   - rabbitmq:rabbit
   - redis:redis

# container with redis worker
worker:
  build: .
  command:
  volumes:
    - .:/code/mobile_api
  links:
    - db:db
    - rabbitmq:rabbit
    - redis:redis
```

Comment: Could edit your question with: the 3 root URL for your 3 PHP websites, the URL you would like to reach the django webapp and also the content of your fig.sh file?

Comment: I also added info about apache and fig.yml above. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what it is you are after? You almost sound a bit like this recent and also slightly confusing question at http://serverfault.com/questions/701634/running-docker-with-apache-wsgi-side-by-side-with-apache/701805 where they wanted to be able to have the Apache on the host proxy through to the Apache in the Docker container. Or are you just wanting to use mod_wsgi in the container rather than the Django development server?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank for help. I wanted to be able to have the Apache on the host proxy through to the Apache in the Docker container. That is my question.

Comment: Then that question I link to should give you a rough idea of the required Apache configuration for doing the proxying.

Comment: agreed with @GrahamDumpleton, the solution to your problem is to make use of apache [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instruction.This question isn't about programming but about web server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more information about the general issues around proxying Apache to backend Python web sites which use mod_wsgi, see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html